# Latest Software Updater: The package system is broken gir1.2-webkit2-4.1

Tags: package-management, update-manager

On U22.10 desktop:

```
> sudo apt upgrade    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.1 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0 (= 2.38.4-0ubuntu0.22.10.1) but 2.38.3-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 is installed
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0 (= 2.38.3-0ubuntu0.22.10.1) but 2.38.4-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 is installed
 libwebkit2gtk-5.0-0 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-5.0-0 (= 2.38.3-0ubuntu0.22.10.1) but 2.38.4-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then

```
> apt policy gir1.2-webkit2-4.1
gir1.2-webkit2-4.1:
  Installed: 2.38.4-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
  Candidate: 2.38.4-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.38.4-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.38.0-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages
```

How do I proceed? `sudo apt --fix-broken install` didn't work.

**UPDATE**

`sudo apt --fix-broken install` finally did work. Not sure what changed. Something upstream maybe?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Please add that to your question along with the output of `apt policy gir1.2-webkit2-4.1`

Comment: No errors with `update` and the OP is the `upgrade` output.

Comment: ? It says the installed version of `gir1.2-webkit2-4.1` is the latest version. No update pending.

Comment: So it's the updater's mistake. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Done. Not much new though.

Comment: Use `sudo apt update ; sudo apt full-upgrade` - not `apt upgrade`.

Comment: Success! I ran `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and it decided to work this time. I suspect the upstream people did something?